# React useCallback and useEffect at the same time messed the state

Tags: reactjs

I created a [SignaturePad](https://github.com/agilgur5/react-signature-canvas) for my application that will pass the value later on to Formik.

**Problem 1:**

I have some issue with using the `useEffect` and `useCallback` function of react. Previously before I add useEffect, `handleClear` function works just fine. However after I added useEffect, `sigPad` refs always returns null in handleClear.

I'm not sure if my mental model is correct, can anyone please explain why is this happening?

**Problem 2:**

I realised however, after I removed the `[sigPad]` at `handleClear` I am able to receive the ref again. Which part of my code re-renders and how does useCallback not realise that sigPad is changing from null to the correct ref?

**Problematic code:**

```
export function Signature() {
  let sigPad = useRef(null);
  const [sig, setSig] = useState("");
  const classes = formStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sigPad);
    setSig(sigPad.toData());
    console.log(sigPad);
  }, [sig]);
  const handleClear = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(sigPad);
    if (sigPad) sigPad.clear();
  }, [sigPad]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <Grid spacing={3} container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <h3 className="text-bold">Signature</h3>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div className="sigCanvas">
            <SignatureCanvas
              penColor="black"
              canvasProps={{ className: "sigPad" }}
              ref={ref => {
                sigPad = ref;
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            component="label"
            className={classes.instructions}
            onClick={handleClear}
          >
            Clear
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Button
            component="label"
            variant="contained"
            className={classes.instructions}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Current Fix:**

```
  const handleClear = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(sigPad);
    if (sigPad) sigPad.clear();
  });
```

**Note**: Before I add useEffect I don't have to remove the `[sigPad]` at my callback

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are executed in the order they are called, this means that your `useEffect` takes precedence over your `useCallback` function. Also, this `[]` is called the dependency array and is used to create new instances of the underlying structure. When using `useRef` you don't need to do this

```js
ref={ref => { sigPad = ref; }}
```

You can just do

```js
ref={sigPad}
```

And try moving your `useCallback` above `useEffect`.